# Don't block on rospy.init_node

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Simple question : is there a way for not blocking on init_node call ?

Doing it (Python) ;

```
      init_node("MyNode", disable_signals=True)
```

if roscore is not launched I get, which is normal, this :

```
      Unable to register with master node [http://localhost:11311/]: master may not be running yet. Will keep trying.
```

However it's not raising ROSException so it just blocks on it. Can we prevent it ?

Thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282587/don%27t-block-on-rospy.init_node/) by [r00t8](https://answers.ros.org/users/33691/r00t8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-02-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r00t8](https://answers.ros.org/users/33691/r00t8/) on 2018-02-14**:
Thank you guys. It does the job.

**Comment by [r00t8](https://answers.ros.org/users/33691/r00t8/) on 2018-02-14**:
Thank you guys. It does the job.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
@r00t8: don't post answers unless you are answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Related question (almost a duplicate): #q10499.

Relevant part of the answer there (from [ros_comm/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/078481c0c113ae8c1c01947e2425e4f8a0ec62d0/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic/__init__.py#L84-L92)):

```
def _check_master():
    try:
        rosgraph.Master('/rostopic').getPid()
    except socket.error:
        raise ROSTopicIOException("Unable to communicate with master!")
```

`_check_master()` is not part of the public API of `rostopic`, but you should be able to use it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-13**:
Note that this is not an actual answer (ie: it doesn't make `rospy.init_node(..)` non-blocking), but your question title and question body don't actually correspond with each other.

This would seem to be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info).